# Android how to call the adapter after the for loop execution

Tags: java, android

```
  private class freeBusy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        for(int i=0;i<stylistidArray.size();i++){
            FirebaseFirestore db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            db.collection("stylists").document(stylistidArray.get(i)).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot=task.getResult();
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                            String stylistid=documentSnapshot.getId();
                            String firstName=documentSnapshot.getString("firstName");
                            String lastName=documentSnapshot.getString("lastName");
                            String imageUrl=documentSnapshot.getString("imageUrl");
                            StylistCollection stylistCollection=new StylistCollection(stylistid,firstName,lastName,imageUrl);
                            stylistDetailsList.add(stylistCollection);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        NewStylistAdapter   newStylistAdapter=new NewStylistAdapter(date,startTime,servicesId,price,stylistidArray,durationList,endTimeList,stylistDetailsList,stylistImg);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecorator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.divider));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newStylistAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        newStylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
 }
```

I am having stylistidArray i want to call the adapter after my for loop condition is satisfied.Here i am trying to call the adapter when the for loop is executing last time but its not working the if statement is executed in starting itself.

Comment: Declare it outside of for loop and instantiate inside, then you can access it outside of your for loop but need to check for `null` every time you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply u need to create the object of `Adapter` globally which can accessable for all like below

```
 YOUR_ADAPTER mAdapter;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   }
```

And notify that whenever u are changing in the list, like below

```
  ArrayList<String> YOUR_ARRAYLIST = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAYLIST.size(); i++) {
            YOUR_ARRAYLIST.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        /**
         * After populating the data on ArrayList than u need to update OR intilaize the  Recyclview
         */


        if (mAdapter!=null) {
            mAdapter = new YOUR_ADAPTER(this, YOUR_ARRAYLIST);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            YOUR_RECYCLVIEW.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            YOUR_RECYCLVIEW.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            YOUR_RECYCLVIEW.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
        else
        {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```